# unreachable statement while compiling

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

I'm doing code to ask for a number and tally the even numbers between 2 and n.

```
    else if (n > 2)
    {
        while (n > r)
        {
            if (n < r)
            {
                break;
                System.out.println(r); <-- now I'm getting an error here "unreachable statement"
            }
            else
            {
                sum +r = sum;
                r = r + 2;                                     
            }
```

So what exactly do I do to make sure it doesn't result in a compile error??

Comment: Assignment is right to left. When do you expect a statement after a `break;` to run?

Comment: Don't edit your question like that. It makes the answers obsolete. If you're having other problems, ask another question or make your edits below the existing code with issues.

Comment: You only enter the `while` loop if `n > r`, so the `if (n < r)` condition will always be false.  So you need to re-think your design, because even if you get rid of the compile error, it's still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`sum + r` is not a variable, and therefore you cannot assign a value to it - hence `sum + r = sum;` is wrong. I assume you meant to have `sum = sum + r;`. This can be further simplified as `sum += r;`.

EDIT:
The question was edited after this answer was posted, so updating it too. `break` exists a loop, so anything after it will be unreachable. Java does not allow such shenanigans, and thus fails the compilation. One way around this would be to perform the printing **before** you break:

```
if (n < r)
{
    System.out.println(r);
    break;
}
else
{
    sum = sum + r;
    r = r + 2;                                     
}
```

Comment: @DavidWallace Updated my answer to handle the updated question.